# How to fix too slow browsing problem to Ubuntu Webserver from Windows Domain Controller Environment?

Tags: webserver, ubuntu-16.04, windows-server-2012-r2, domaincontroller

I had a Web Server, which is configured with Ubuntu. Some web applications are hosted there and Clients from windows user browse/use those applications through the network. Application accessibility was smoother and faster and also was running without any interruptions.

But all the issues start when I configure the Windows Server and put all the users under a DOMAIN CONTROLLER. Now all the applications accessibility become too slow. Sometimes some pages are not loading at all.

I am mentioning all the IP configurations bellow-

- Network Default Gateway: 172.16.0.1/16
- Web Server-  172.16.2.2/16
- Windows Server (Domain Controller)-  172.16.3.1/16
  Using this Windows Server IP as DNS IP for all Client PC and also for the Web server.
- Clients IP range: 172.16.1.1 to 172.16.10.254

Please See the Graphical view of my Configuration from the link below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEUMR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It was a DNS issue. I restored the Previous DNS settings in all clients and server then everything goes to normal condition.